# libreoffice --convert-to only running as root

Tags: shell, permissions, pdf-generation, root, libreoffice

I'm trying to convert an OpenDocument to PDF using LibreOffice's command without GUI. But, it only works when running the command as root (with sudo). Otherwise, nothing happens.

```
$ libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf file.odg
```

Searching on the web, I found that the ~/.config/libreoffice folder and all subfolders on it have to be owned by the user. I checked it and still doesn't work.

Why do I need to use root power just to create a PDF?

Thanks,